# How do I namespace a model in Laravel so as not to clash with an existing class?

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4 I want to use a model that represents an `Event` coming from my database. Thus, in `app/models` I have my `Event` model that extends Eloquent.

However, Laravel 4 already has an `Event` class which is used to manage events within the application lifecycle.

What I want to know is, how can I properly namespace my `Event` model and access it in a way that will not clash with the existing `Event` class.

Comment: The same way you use namespaces in other places? Only need to register it.

Comment: Does that mean I namespace it according to the directory it is in? For example `namespace Model` and then access it using `Model\Event`?

Comment: Yes. The documentation has an example in model section.

Comment: I couldn't find anything on namespacing in the Laravel 4 beta documentation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to apply a namespace to it as you normally would. So, for example.

```
<?php namespace Models;

use Eloquent;

class Event extends Eloquent {

}
```

You should then correctly setup your `composer.json` so that it loads your models. You could use `classmap` or `psr-0` for this, depending on whether or not you're following PSR-0 with your directory structure.

I'm pretty sure the `models` directory is already mapped.

**Edit**
As mentioned in the comments you must run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: This did the trick, didn't even think of running `composer dump-autoload` but now it works.

Comment: Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php hasMany Crashes with Class 'Event' not found

Answer (score 0):

**As much i have research about using namespaces, because i want to use those inside the PHPDocumentar, its not possible to add twice the namespaces, as laravel already adds those for you, if we understand the basic problem, why we use namespaces**

1 - many libraries uses same class name, so we use namespaces to differentiate that.

2 - if you want to use namespaces then you should be out of the scope of the app, means is the vendor folder for you to this kind of stuff.

Enjoy